# Load testing for web mobile application for Android

Tags: android

Can LoadRunner do load testing for web mobile application of Android? I

Answer (score 2):

Here are two tutorials which may help to record network traffic of Android (iOS, Windows Mobile, etc.) devices using HP Loadrunner 9.5x:

1) Using the Android SDK emulator:
http://www.perftesting.co.uk/recording-and-performance-testing-android-applications-with-hp-loadrunner-vugen/

2) Using the real "hard" device (combined with DNS spoofing to send the network traffic through the Hp Loadrunner Virtual User Generator):
http://www.perftesting.co.uk/performance-testing-iphone-ios-android/

Answer (score 0):

Yes.   There are potentially multiple ways of capturing the conversion, from using an Android simulator running on a PC to using VUGEN as an HTTP man-in-the-middle proxy to record the conversation passed from an Android device through VUGEN and onto the final target.

Comment: thanks james, please tell me which simulator is better to record android based application. If possible provide open source name.

Comment: Use the simulator of your choice.  Or what I would do is simply use an actual android handset, combined with the proxy recording model and wifi connectivity from the handset, to record a live session from an android device.

Answer (score 0):

I used jMeter for this purposes. 
[Load Test Mobile Apps](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/186249-load-test-mobile-apps-easily-)  article provides you clear steps